# getting minimum value after tapply

Tags: r

I started learning R recently, and I am completely new. Sorry if my question will seem lame to some of you but I have spent more than an hour trying to research how to do this using indexing or subset but couldn't find anything.
So here it goes :
I have a file which has

```
temperature lower rain month yr
10.8        6.5  12.2  1     1987
10.5        4.5  1.3   1     1987
7.5         -1   0.1   1     1987
```

This file contains 6,940 lines of data.

I read the file in R. and I wanted to find the average rainfall per year for which i used :

```
A <- tapply(temperature,yr,mean)
```

this function returned:

```
    1987     1988     1989     1990     1991     1992     1993     1994     1995     1996     1997     1998     1999     2000     2001     2002     2003     2004     2005
    13.27014 13.79126 15.54986 15.62986 14.11945 14.61612 14.30984 15.12877 15.81260 13.98082 15.63918 15.02568 15.63736 14.94071 14.90849 15.47589 16.03260 15.25109 15.06000
```

Now the question is I need the year where the average rain is the min. 
when I apply :

```
min(A)
```

It returns 13.27014 which corresponds for the year 1987 but how do I query for the year which corresponds to the min Value.
And when I try :

```
A[,min(A)]
```

It  returns an error

Sorry again for the lame question but this is driving me crazy

Comment: This should work `names(A)[which.min(A)]`, or also `names(A)[A==min(A)]`.

Comment: Oh cool thanks ! i was dumb enough to try assignment instead of comparison A[A=min(A)] which obviously didn't work.

Comment: By the way: `which.min` is faster.

Comment: Great thanks ! correct me if I'm mistaken but this is a vector (or 1 dimensional array) how do i split the values ? to get only the temperature or year

Comment: `which.min` will handle ties by selecting the first occurrence of the minimum. Be sure that that is the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: to split the names off `names(A)` is a vector of names, `unname(A)` is a vector of values.

Comment: @PierreLafortune thanks for the names and unname functions these are exactly what I needed. About the min i think the first occurence is  good enough but just out of curiosity, is there a way to list all of them ?

Comment: Use the second solution from the first comment

Comment: you might want look into the `aggregate()` function too. would look like: `aggregate(rain ~ yr, dataframe, mean)`